# Log transformed variable

Tags: r, regression, transformation

I need in your advice. I have a problem with continuous variables. They are not normal-distributed, so I log transformed them and then performed Shapiro-W test and got the next result: W = NaN, p-value = NA.
I need to use them in Multinominal linear regression as a dependent variable, but R with log transformed variables give me Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'. I found the commands on the tutorials and forums where people asked how to deal with this problem. Thus, I tried the next command to exclude NaN and Inf from logSJC28 - lm_SJC28.1[is.na(lm_SJC28.1) | lm_SJC28.1 == "Inf"] <- NA. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Maybe you have something on your mind according to your experience?
Mult Linear Reg with the same variables without log transformation was performed without of any problems.

```
> shapiro.test(logSJC28.1)

   Shapiro-Wilk normality test
data:  logSJC28.1
W = NaN, p-value = NA
```

They are for sure continuous. Also, I checked if those two variables have any missing value that has been mistakenly replaced by a symbol etc in the file. Nothing was reviled. Hope for your help.

```
> shapiro.test(logSJC28.1)

Shapiro-Wilk normality test
data:  logSJC28.1
W = NaN, p-value = NA
```

They are for sure continuous. Also, I checked if those two variables have any missing value that has been mistakenly replaced by a symbol etc in the file. Nothing was reviled. Hope for your help.

Comment: Greetings! It is usually helpful to provide some reproducible form of your data so people can help you. In this case it would be extra helpful to show your non-transformed data. One option is by sharing the `dput` of your data like shown here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you! It was helpfull. I replased Inf. with NA. Now it works